# How to get SSURGO Soil Shapefile Directly inside QGIS?

Tags: qgis, soil

SSURGO Soil data can be downloaded from websoilsurvey https://websoilsurvey.sc.egov.usda.gov/App/HomePage.htm by creating an AOI and then checking out, but this is a tedious process. Is there a way to get the Soil Layer Directly inside QGIS by just giving an area of interest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSURGO Soil data can be downloaded directly inside the QGIS by a plugin called Curve Number Generator. https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/curve_number_generator/.

The plugin can be downloaded from the official repository inside QGIS.

[image]

It will download soil data for any area under 100,000 acres within the contiguous United States.

Disclaimer: I am the author of this plugin.